# How to cout information of inherited class C++

Tags: c++, class, g++, operator-keyword

So I have a class named animal and the inherited class people

```
class animal
{
  private:
    private:
    string type;
    string name;
    unsigned int age;
    string gender;
  public:
    animal():type("Unknown"),name("Unknown"),age(0),gender("Unknown"){}
    animal(string t,string n="Unknown",unsigned int a=0,string g="Unknown"):type(t),name(n),age(a),gender(g){}
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,animal& obj)
  { 
    os << "Name : " << obj.name << endl << "Type : " << obj.type << endl << "Age : " << obj.age << endl << "Gender : " << obj.gender << endl;
    return os;
  }
};

class people:public animal
{
  private:
    string education;
  public:   
    people():animal(),education("Unknown"){}
    people(string t,string n="Unknown",unsigned int a=0,string g="Unknown",string e="Unknown"):animal(t,n,a,g),education(e){}
friend std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream& os, people const& obj)
{
os << "Name : " << obj.name << endl << "Type : " << obj.type << endl << "Age : " << obj.age << endl << "Gender : " << obj.gender << endl << "Education : " << obj.education <<endl;//cant access to private members of animal class , but i want to cout them
return os;
}
};
```

and this is my main function

```
int main()
{
  people me("People","Karen",16,"Male","Magistratus");
  cout << me;
}
```

Question : How can I do

cout << me;//people class not animal

with operator<< ?

Comment: missing `const`, it should be `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const animal& obj)`

Comment: `const` is not mandatory.

Comment: Using safety guards when handling a chainsaw isn't mandatory either...

Comment: Your code works (once fixed typo `string,g`) : (http://ideone.com/JRSoMt)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `<<` operator for your class like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, class_name const& obj)
{
   return o << obj.name;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that would change anything (except for the `const` allowing to bind rvalues.)

Comment: After adding the `operator<<` method, you can add this virtual method to you base class to force the children to override the method:
`virtual void operator << (ostream& os) const = 0;`

Comment: That "virtual method" operator would have the operands in the wrong order. The duplicate has some good answers showing how to do this polymorphically.

Answer (score 0):

[Your code worked perfectly](http://ideone.com/kxlbyd) once the instruction `string,g="Unknown"` present here:

```
animal(string t,string n="Unknown",unsigned int a=0,string,g="Unknown"):type(t),name(n),age(a),gender(g){}
```

Was fixed to:

```
animal(string t,string n="Unknown",unsigned int a=0,string g="Unknown"):type(t),name(n),age(a),gender(g){}
```